# Naming paths and moving repetitive code outside scope

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to move the repetitive path code `(-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25)` out of the scoped environment. Can I name this path and then reference it inside the scoped block.

```
  \begin{scope} [mem/.style={upper left=gray!40, very thin}]
    \node[draw, black, thick, minimum width =4cm,
          minimum height=6cm, fill=teal!15] (rambox) at (-1.5,0) {};
    \node[black,scale=1.0] at (-1.5,2.7) {\textsf{MEMORY}};
    \node[blue,scale=0.8] at (-1.5,-2.7) {$2^{32}$ bytes $\approx 4.29$ GB};

    \node [matrix] (ram) at (-1.5,0)
    {
      \node[blue] {Address} ;&  \node[blue] {Content}; & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0xffffffff}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem] (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) -- cycle ;  & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0xfffffffe}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem] (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) -- cycle ;  & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0xfffffffd}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem] (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) -- cycle ;  & \\
      \node {$\ddots$} ;&  \node{$\ddots$}; & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0x00000003}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem]  (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) --cycle ; & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0x00000002}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem]  (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) --cycle ; & \\
      \node { \memcellsize \texttt{0x00000001}} ;&  \shadedraw [mem]  (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25); & \\
      \node {  \memcellsize \texttt{0x00000000}} ;& \shadedraw [mem]  (-0.5,.25) -- (-0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,-.25) -- (0.5,.25) ; & \\
    };
  \end{scope}
```

Similarly, I want to move the `Stealth{}` given below option to the beginning of the tikz environment.

```
\draw[{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},thick] (iocntrl) -- (storage1);
\draw[{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},thick] (iocntrl) |- (rambox) node [near end, fill=white, text width = 1.5cm] {\footnotesize{Load/Store}};
\draw[{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},thick] (iocntrl) |- (regbox) node [near start, fill=white] {\footnotesize{syscall}};
\draw[{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},thick] (iocntrl) -- (userio);
```

Comment: You can just define a macro `\newcommand*\mypath{(-0.5,2.5) …}` and use that `\shadedraw[mem] \mypath -- cycle;` (or w/o `-- cycle`). You can also do `mypath/.style={insert path={(-0.5, 2.5) …}}` and use `\shadedraw[mem, mypath] -- cycle;`. For the arrow tip, if you will use that specific tip everywhere, do `>={Stealth[…]}` and just use `<->`. (You can always define a style `myarrow/.style={thick, {Stealth[…]}-{Stealth[…]}}` and use just that `\draw[myarrow] …;`. You can also define a new arrow tip like `mytip/.tip={Stealth[…]}` and use that instead: `mytip-mytop`. So many possibilites!

Comment: Excellent that worked!